# how to get all values of selected checkbox in vb.net and set it on string list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to get selected items on checkbox and set as string format like (value1,value2,value3) from the checkbox i selected

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows    
    If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim CheckRow As CheckBox = (TryCast(row.Cells(1).FindControl("chckSelector"), CheckBox))

        If CheckRow.Checked Then
            Dim scode As String = TryCast(row.Cells(2).FindControl("lblsstorecode"), Label).Text
            lbltest.Text = 'this i want to get the value like this (value1,value2,value3) from checkbox that i selected                
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: From your previous post you had a list of checkboxes right? Why don't you loop it and store the value of the checked ones?

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know how to do that.. Can you please show me what im going to do

Comment: I'm not on my pc to give proper code but you should do this: Create a list of string, make a for each chk as checkbox in checklist and check if chk.checked = True then list.add(chk.text), try this approach

Comment: Ok sir im trying to do it.

Comment: Or you can do something that might be better, you can use CheckBox.CheckedChanged to add or remove the value from the list, it's up to you

Comment: as you mention above sir im going to add it into the list?

Comment: but i need is to get the selected value and set it as string like valu1,value2,value3

Comment: The value you want is the checkbox's text or another value you assigned to each checkbox? If it's the checkbox's text use what i said in the first comment if it's the value use the latest comment

Comment: The checkbox is on the gridview not on the checkboxlist

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VsxcZ92.png check this

Comment: ah ok lbltest should not be a label to store your values as array, use listtest as a list of string instead: listtest.add(scode).

Comment: thank so much for reply.. But i got the final answer and thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on why you are using the GridView control, you might me able to accomplish this easier by using a CheckBoxList instead. In Asp.net what you describe is accomplished very easily with a CheckBoxList as follows:

In .aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Itemlst" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

</br>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</br>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim selected = New List(Of ListItem)
    Dim itemcount As Integer
    Dim csvlist As String = ""
    For Each item As ListItem In Itemlst.Items
        If item.Selected Then selected.Add(item)
    Next

    itemcount = selected.Count
    For i = 0 To itemcount - 1
        csvlist = csvlist & selected(i).ToString & ","
    Next
    csvlist = Mid(csvlist, 1, Len(csvlist) - 1)
    TextBox1.Text = csvlist
End Sub
```

The Windows Forms CheckedListBox would probably work similar if you are developing a desktop application.